# Book-recommendation: Ethology

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that covers the following topics in ethology:

- **Behaviour**

  - Sensory filtering, reponsive-ness, sign stimuli, learning and memory, instinct, habituation, conditioning, imprinting.
- **Role of hormones in drive**

  - role of pheromones in alarm spreading; crypsis, predator detection, predator tactics, social hierarchies in primates, social organization in insects.
- **Navigation and Biological Rythms**

  - Orientation, navigation, homing, biological rhythms, biological clock, tidal, seasonal and circadian rhythms.
- **Methodology**

  - Methods for studying animal behaviour including sexual conflict, selfishness, kinship and altruism.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I edited your question. I think it looks better like this and will attract more attention and better answers. Good design is essential for a good communication. There is probably still room for improving your question if you want to give a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will take care in the future for he same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest three books, none of them cover all those aspects, though:

1) The Foundations of Ethology, Konrad Lorenz. The best introduction I know for the field of ethology. Lorenz is called by some "the father of ethology".

2) Sociobiology: The New Synthesis, Edward Wilson. The deepest study of animal societies I know of.

3) Evolutionary Ecology, Eric Pianka. If my memory is right, it says something about the Navigation and Biological Rythms part.